# Image display depending on the parameter

Tags: javascript, html, angular

There are two parameters: `date_begin` (Date added) and `date_end` (Date delete). And I have a list where all users are displayed. And opposite each user there is an icon of a tick and a cross. These icons should vary depending on the parameters. Those. If only the parameter `date_begin` is filled, then the icon is displayed as a checkmark. Well, if both the `date_begin` and `date_end` parameters are filled in then the icon is displayed as a cross. The problem is that at the moment I have a cross icon opposite each user, although not all users have this option. How can this be remedied?

```
<div class="list-group" >
    <div class="media" *ngFor="let user of users">
        <a class="list-group-item ">
            <h4 class=" media-heading list-group-item-heading"> {{user.full_name}} </h4>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <p class="list-group-item-text">{{user.position}}</p>     
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="media-left ">
                        <a *ngIf="(user.date_end$)">
                            <img class="media-object" src="assets/img/icon/checked.png" title="Uploaded">
                        </a>
                        <a *ngIf="!(user.date_end$)">
                            <img class="media-object" src="assets/img/icon/unchecked.png" title="Removed">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: my 2 cents, i think you should interchange the images, "second" condition is TRUE when date_end$ is not present and would result in UNCHECKED(cross) image displayed.
is date_end$ an observable? If not, if possible consider removing '$' from the end(usually $ is added for observables).

Comment: @Avij Thanks, understood